# I need a Makefile.am rule to update include file

Tags: gnu-make, autotools, automake

I have a `Makefile.am` that looks something like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = prog

AM_CFLAGS = $(prog_CFLAGS)

prog_SOURCES = \
    data.h \
    src1.c \
    src2.c \
    ...
    src30.c
```

The `data.h` file is sometimes updated by a `update_data.pl` perl script depending on certain conditions. I tried adding this to the end of `Makefile.am`:

```
.PHONY: data.h
data.h:
    perl update_data.pl
```

but the script never runs. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: It never runs because it has no prerequisites, and the file exists, so it's never considered out of date by make.  Make works by comparing last modified times on files.  So you'll have to either (a) rebuild it every time, or else (b) figure out one or more other files which, if changed, means that this header needs to be updated.

Comment: But marking it `.PHONY`, as the OP has done, should cause it to be rebuilt every time, regardless of whether it already exists, should it not, @MadScientist?

Comment: No, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html. "A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that file. As long as a phony target is never a prerequisite of a real target, the phony target recipe will be executed only when the phony target is a specified goal."

Comment: Yes, `.PHONY` will do that.  Somehow I didn't notice that.  Weird, must be shelter-in-place blindness.  However, it will only be rebuilt if it's listed as a prerequisite of some target that is to be built.  I don't know what the automake generated output will do with `prog_SOURCES` but if it filters out `.h` files for example and doesn't leave them as a prerequiste on any target, because make expects dependency generation to manage headers, then it won't be rebuilt.  You may have to mark it as a prerequisite explicitly in the `.am` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally got it to work. Using `$(shell)` may not be the best way, but it works.

```
bin_PROGRAMS = prog

AM_CFLAGS = $(prog_CFLAGS)

update_data := $(shell ./update_data.pl > /dev/tty)

prog_SOURCES = \
    data.h \
    src1.c \
    src2.c \
    ...
    src30.c
```

Comment: You can move the `$(shell)` stuff into a `GNUmakefile.in` which does `include Makefile` and then does `dummy := $(shell ...)`. Then `configure` can generate a `GNUmakefile` via `AC_CONFIG_FILES([GNUmakefile])`. Then the `$(shell ...)` stuff works whenever you are running GNU make. Which is where `$(shell ...)` works. With non-GNU make, only the normal automake `Makefile`s will be active.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a `data.h` file, and it doesn't depend on anything, `make` thinks there's nothing to do to update it.

There's not really a good way to tell `make` to always recreate the file. You can have it depend on the `update_data.pl` file, if you want to regenerate it when you update the script. Or you can have it depend on the data file (as well as the script) if it's parsing and converting a data file.

But if your build is not hermetic, and the content depends on something `make` can't know about, there's no good way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar for updating a header file with a few defines depending on the current git branch, HEAD commit, tree dirty state.

There might be a few uncaught corner cases, but it works for me. May it give you some inspiration.

```
CLEANFILES    += git-info.h
BUILT_SOURCES += git-info.h.stamp
git-info.h.stamp:
        echo "#ifndef GIT_INFO_H" > git-info.h.new
        echo "#define GIT_INFO_H" >> git-info.h.new
        echo "..." >> git-info.h.new
        echo "#endif" >> git-info.h.new
        if test -f git-info.h && cmp git-info.h.new git-info.h; then :; \
        else cat git-info.h.new > git-info.h; fi; \
        rm -f git-info.h.new
```

Notes:

- The stamp file is never created, and thus this rule will always be
  executed on "make all" (not on "make my-program", though).
- `git-info.h` is only ever touched if it has actually changed. This
  avoids rebuilds caused just by an updated timestamp of `git-info.h`
  without any changes to the content.
- To reduce the rebuild effort when `git-info.h` *has* changed, I
  only include the generated `git-info.h` header from a single
  regular C `my_program_SOURCES` source file `git-info.c` which
  then defines a few global `char foo[] = FOO;` symbols which
  will then be linked to the final executable.
- The `git-info.o` file will automatically depend on `git-info.h`,
  which will cause a rebuild when the header has changed.